# How to check if element width is greater than 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if my element is greater than 100% in width - so if the `div` is 113.42% hide something else, but I cannot get it to hide elements.

Right now, I have this set up to test, if the width is greater than 100% make background black else make background red. Right now, the elements are red but the elements that are greater than 100% are not turning black. Can someone pin point what I am doing wrong? It is also doing it to all elements I want to detect on each element with `.display-area` - do I have to use the `.each` function?

```
        var $displayarea = $(".display-area");
        var width = $('.display-area').width();
        var parentWidth = $('.display-area').offsetParent().width();
        var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
//      var per = $('.first-div').width() * .80;
//      if ( $displayarea.width() > "100%" )  {
        if ($displayarea.css("width") > percent ) {
                $displayarea.css({ 
                        background: 'black'
                });

        } else {

                $displayarea.css({
                        background: 'red'
                });

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see the values of the comparison you are doing? css("width") will return a string with units, IE. "10px" whereas .width() doesn't. It could be you are doing if("10px" > 10) which would always return false.

Comment: For the second part - yes you need to use an `.each` because `$displayarea` is a collection of all `.display-area` divs. So when you set `$displayarea.css ...` you are setting that css style on every `.display-area`.

Comment: how do i write that? @samuelmr

Comment: @Bryan, if you are using Chrome there is an excellent javascript debugger built in. The F12 key will bring it up and you can find your javascript in the sources tab, from here you can click the left had side bar which will place a break point. When the code is ran you can hover over each variable to give you more information about it.

Comment: all i want to do is check if element has a greater width of 100 percent. this doesn't answer the question. can you help pointing me in the right direction? @samuelmr

Comment: @BryanBarrera 100 percent of what? It's parent? The window?

Comment: yes the parent container of `.display-area` @zgood if its larger than 100% do something else do something else

Comment: Hey do you want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8tzcawkL/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are after, but you can check out a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7e1z56ac/).

```
$(function () {
    var $displayarea = $(".display-area");
    var parentWidth = $('.display-area').parent().width();

    $displayarea.each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > parentWidth) {
            $(this).css({
                background: 'black'
            });

        } else {
            $(this).css({
                background: 'red'
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: dude! this helped man! appreciate it! @zgood, i couldn't wrap my head around it

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the widths of the `html` tag and the element by using their respective `css` selectors.

```
if($('div').css("width").replace("px","") > $('html').css("width").replace("px",""))
    alert($('div').css("width").replace("px","") - $('html').css("width").replace("px","")  + " more");
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible here is what you are searching:

```
var parent = $('.parentDiv').width();
var child = $('.childDiv').width();

var percent = child * 100 / parent;

if (percent > 100) {
   $('.childDiv').css('background-color', '#000')
} else {
   $('.childDiv').css('background-color', '#f00')
}
```

Comment: You can do this: `$('.parentDiv').width()` no need to `.replace('px', '');`

Answer (score -1):

you need check on resize event

```
like $('.display-size').bind('resize',function(){
//logic
})
```